# How to keep mysql query with pagination

Tags: php, mysql, filter, pagination

I am trying to keep my pagination based on the query I am using, but my problem is it only works on the first page of pagination, and after that the query reverts to the standard one without filters (page one shows my filter, but page two show all results). I am wondering if there is an effective method that will carry over my filtered query when I click my pages, I am just at a loss right now as to how to accomplish this. Im using dig style pagination?

Comment: @RiggsFolly the pagination works well but not when i put a filter through input in query statement, pagination for the filtered query works only in the firstpage but when i go to the second page the mysql query reverts to standart one (without filters)

Comment: So show us the code, otherwise we can only make guesses. People will soon loose interest in a question they cannot answer and soon the question will get closed with `Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.` See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I think 15 minutes should be enough to add some code to your question. As you have not done so, I assume you are not going to. Your previous 2 questions were also rather short on details so for future reference can I suggest you read [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) If you ever want to get the best out of SO

Answer (score 0):

Do you use a start parameter in your sql query?
i keep the page in the url as get parameter and then calculate in my code the startpoint and use

```
LIMIT 0, 10
```

then for the second page

```
LIMIT 10, 10
```

then

```
LIMIT 20, 10
```

Comment: thats not what i asked, pagination is there and functional but not when i filter the query, because when i go to page number 2 it shows the unfiltered query

Comment: So show us your code, or all yu are going to get is more guesses like this

Answer (score 0):

You should check the sql that pass to the database. If the pagination works, there should be like:

```
Limit n offset m.
```

or

```
Limit n, m. //same as above.
```